# Face recognition using javacv android

Tags: android, face-recognition, javacv

I had tried with javacv face recognition library. 
 I can successfully recognize two static images but in inconsistent way. It is returning correct result, but same scenario with different images not getting result, it is throwing an error.

Scenario 1: Same Two Images(i.e. imag1.png), Same Size in terms of bytes and in terms of height and width 
Result of scenario 1: Correct.

Now I am changing images.

Scenario 2: Same Two Images(i.e. imag2.png), Same Size in terms of bytes and in terms of height and width 
Result of scenario 2: Throwing an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: /home/saudet/workspace/android/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/legacy/src/eigenobjects.cpp:1629: error: (-5) Different sizes of objects in function cvEigenDecomposite
```

what could be the resolution of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By java cv face recognition library do you mean the FaceRecognition.Java in the samples or the FaceRecognizer in the contrib module of opencv/javacv?

In the case of the first one, FaceRecognition.java I was just getting the same error when converting a bitmap to an IplImage and passing that to cvEigenDecomposite.

I am pretty sure what the error means is that your IplImage is the wrong size. I was using the At&T database so I just resized my bitmap before I converted it to IplImage and then it worked.

So perhaps they aren't the same size or something is going wrong when creating the IplImage.